# Save date to DB use thread or service or others Android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I am not sure which I should use when the OS tell me the ANR when I want to save date to DB.
I think there is no UI, so Service is Ok. 
Could some one tell what Are Pros and Cons?
And do you think it is stupid if I use a progress dialog and to do the saving?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Use IntentService...Its simple n efficient.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my English skill :P

So if u want to save something in sqlite u can do it in UI or in some Async task, or in a service.

Exemple for usage: 
    if u have some big data what u want to save, better if u do that in a service, check the service lifcycle [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)!
    if u have some image u can do it in asynctask and u don't need to block the ui thread.
    for any small thing u can use the ui thread.

Never forget if ur ui thread can't react to any user indication the Android engine will kill ur ap, thats why u need to do this in back if u have a lot of data.

[A good AsyncTask tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)!

Comment: Thank umair.all and Arnold. Do you guys have some ideas if I want to catch the exception and let my UI thread to wait the result....

Comment: I don't understand what u need now :P the thread where u call try / catch will wait till when u take an exception or just finished the method. The try / catch method running is a single catch(or just working like that). So ur thread will wait till thats method is end.